# can't open new notebook with particular kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have a jupyter notebook server with multiple kernels.  every time I try to start a new notebook with my deepdow2 kernel it hangs for a long time and ultimately the connection fails with:

"A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration."

I created the deepdow2 virtual env with the commands below:

```
conda create -n deepdow2 python=3.5source activate deepdow2conda install -c Quantopian ziplineconda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorchpip install deepdowconda install -c anaconda ipykernel
```

when the notebook fails to connect with the deepdow2 kernel, the terminal shows the errors below.

error:

```
File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/deepdow2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/parso/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from parso.parser import ParserSyntaxError
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/deepdow2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/parso/parser.py", line 113
    node_map: Dict[str, type] = {}
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[W 04:37:48.190 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 04:37:48.191 NotebookApp] Kernel 1240f39b-c74e-4246-a8de-16b6560782cb died, removing from map.
[W 04:37:54.213 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 1240f39b-c74e-4246-a8de-16b6560782cb:07b0ca22e4564a7b8f7839595b3b0a6d
[W 04:38:16.241 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 1240f39b-c74e-4246-a8de-16b6560782cb:07b0ca22e4564a7b8f7839595b3b0a6d
```

does anyone know what the issue might be and can you suggest how to fix it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @user3476463 ?

Comment: If anyone ever lands on this page while using a new mac os, my solution was to uninstall anaconda3 from the MacHD and reinstall it in my user folder. It was so much easier to use anaconda3 from my user folder, rather than trying to run it from Mac OS systems folders (this was on Big Sur, BTW).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it as follow:

1. uninstall your jupyter notebook. Click on the setting button (top-right) of the jupyter notebook box and select uninstall and wait for the process to finish.
   [image]
2. then, install jupyter notebook again.
3. and hopefully you would able to launch it now.